# Fast hashing algorithm for mapping/quantizing a collection of floats onto a small set of sorted floats

Tags: sorting, search-algorithms

With my application, I have

- Collection X: thousands of floating-point numbers with the value range [0, 1], not sorted.
- Collection Y: 11 floats ranging from [0, 1], sorted.
- The size of X is known. Let it be L.

The goal is to quantize X and map it onto Y, so that we get a hash array of indices of Y for X. Eventually Y will be then quantized onto 10 discrete things pointed to it.

An example to make it a bit clearer,

- `Y = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]`
- `X = [0.678, 0.124, ..., 1.0, ., 0.013, 0.475]`

I want the algorithm output to be 0-based indices like these:

- `H(Y[0]) = H(0.678) = 6`
- `H(Y[1]) = H(0.124) = 1`
- `H(Y[n-2]) = H(0.013) = 0`
- `H(Y[n-1]) = H(0.475) = 4`

### Attempts

Naively, I've tried linear and binary searching for positioning each element of X in Y so that the element is found between an adjacent pair of elements in Y.

However, the performance is not good enough for my application. This quantization happens in a realtime thread that slow computation is undesirable.

### Question

What is the best way of this kind of hashing/quantization? X is not sorted.

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't defined what exactly it is that your output should be. It's very unclear to me.

Comment: @orlp I updated my question. Would you take a look at it again?

Comment: I still don't see what the *quantised value* or *index* shall be good for. I take $Y$ to *always* be `11` values: If they are equidistant like the example (or follow a similarly simple pattern), state so *in the question*. For any given value $x$, is it a requirement that the index $H(y)$ of a lower value $y$ is no higher than $H(x)$? Is it necessary that for a uniform distribution of $X$ values the expected standard deviation of $H(X)$ is low? Is it mandatory that $H(y)$ on one computer/language system is the same as $H(y)$ on a different one? Beware idiosyncrasies of *floating point*.

Comment: Please add to your question: How did you establish `the performance is not good enough for my application`? (In a different context, you would be urged to add a sketch of the overall task to accomplish, too.)

Comment: @greybeard Let's just say that I have 10 discrete things to select from based on what floats I have at hand. These 10 things thus span a linear space for the floats to fit in. The floats happen to be in the same value range, but they must be eventually quantized onto the 1-10 ints. Would that make more sense? Sorry I might have posted requirements that I haven't got completely straight.

Comment: @greybeard Unfortunately it would be quite distracting to report the entire application context here. But it suffices to say that I have a realtime thread where computation in its main loop should be as fast as possible. But I found out that the searches ate up too much CPU there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take X, multiplied by say 10,000, rounded down to the nearest integer. In plain C, z = (int) (x times 10000.0).

There are 10,000 possible values of z. For most values of z, you can determine the index from z. So create a table with 10,000 entries. In the table, store an index i if you can prove that x should be mapped to i, knowing z, and store -1 if you can’t prove this.

As a result, you get the correct value probably in 9,980 of 10,000 values, and then you use whatever slow algorithm you have for the remaining 1 in 500 values.

PS. The same table size would be used for double precision numbers. Whatever the table size, there will be only few values X that cannot be mapped correctly using this method, maybe 10 or 20. If you take a table of size 10,000 then 99.8% or 99.9% are mapped correctly, and 0.1% or 0.2% need a slow algorithm. The exact same thing happens with double. You could use 1000 entries, then the 10 or 20 failing ones would be 1% or 2%.

And a nice thing is that this method will work however the Y values are distributed. Only if the number of Y values is larger, then you might want to increase the table size.

Comment: Nice. I had a vague idea of this but wasn't sure if it's 100% accurate. So a coarse-to-fine 2-pass approach. Thanks. Will give it a try.

Comment: One more question: you cited 10000 because we assume 32bit floats, correct? For double-precision floats we'd have a bigger table?